# Initial view controller and Tab View Controller

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I'm working with a single view app but also I'm using Tab View controller at one case , but the Tab view Controller must be put as initial view controller to work so how I can use Tab view controller without make it as initial view Controller?

[image]

Comment: You need a navigation controller or custom view controller as root view controller for a tab. Your tab view controller doesn't need to be initial view controller. What prevent you from using tab view controller?

Comment: I'm starting app with normal view controller and then when click on one button I move to Tab view controller , when I used Tab view controller without make it as initial view controller the app display white screen for me without Tab bar at bottom but when make it as initial view controller it appears normally

Comment: Can you post the code snippet?

Comment: All things is done through layout not through code , I will update my post with picture for Tab View only

Comment: What is the problem with setting tabViewController as initial view controller?

Comment: @ldindu with putting it as initial view it's working correctly but without making it as initial view the screen appears without Tab Bar and I need the second case without putting it as initial view

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you are clicking on button to move tabbar controller

Provide a storyboard id to tabbar and use below code

Write this as a class method in appdelegate and call it on button click

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let diallerTBC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarStoryboardId") as! UITabBarController

        self.window?.rootViewController = diallerTBC
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

I hope this will work

Thanks

Comment: with this code, we are changing root view controller, so if we want to go back to VC which contains button, then we again need to change the root view controller!

Comment: one more thing can be done just present/push the tabbarcontroller without animation when you are clicking to next button.

Comment: @ChandanPrajapati I will the last two lines because already I write the first two lines to go to Tab activity

Comment: @ChandanPrajapati thank you for your note the error is resolved only by this line 
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabMessagesVC") as! UITabBarController
The error from me because I was writing UIViewController instead of UITabBarController 
I didn't need to the last two lines

Comment: @ChandanPrajapati In this case how I can send variable from my current view controller to Tab view controller  to use this variable at all tabs?

Answer (score 0):

@SamahAhmed

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let diallerTBC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarStoryboardId") as! MyTabbarController

//create a variable for e.g : data at MyTabbarController and set like

diallerTBC.data = "testing"
```

Comment: But I don't have swift file for the Tab Controller view only I have three files for the three tabs and when I'm putting this variable at these files and try to send value to this variable through current view logically it told to me the Tab Controller view doesn't have this variable where I can create this variable to arrive it from all tabs ?

Comment: Just create a custom class to your tabar controller and create a variable in that class